# Chrome not showing :after pseudo selector

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

Really bugging me, but why isn't Chrome showing the :after pseudo selector?? I haven't noticed this before. It's quite simple CSS too. It shows in all other browsers as well!

### Firefox

[image: Firefox]

### Chrome

[image: Chrome]

I did notice on the Bootstrap site though, their forms are showing the `:after` selector in the DOM. Weird...

[image: Bootstrap form]

Please look at this code snippet that I made. It's doing it here too if you inspect the DOM in your browser. -

```css
.form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-horizontal .form-group:before {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.form-horizontal .form-group:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>First Name *</label>
    <input id="txtCustodianFName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Last Name *</label>
    <input id="txtCustodianLName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you are not defining the `content`, if you do, it will be visible: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrhsk8ys/

Comment: No `content`, no `:after`. Simple as that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `content` property is required for `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors. If it is not included, it will have no effect on the element. If you are using the selectors to preform a clearfix, or some other case where you don't actually want any content, you can simply leave the `content` property blank with `content:'';` Like you have already done for the `:before` selector. Your CSS should look like this:

```
.form-horizontal .form-group:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
```

[Learning To Use The :before And :after Pseudo-Elements In CSS](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/#basic-syntax)

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrhsk8ys/)

Comment: Oh wow... can't believe I missed that. Pretty sure I knew that, but must've forgotten for some reason. Thanks a lot!